# Insert a image in a UIBarButtonItem iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, ios7.1

I have a problem, I need to insert an image in a UIBarButtonItem, but it doesn't shows the button with the image.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //.........

    UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuVC];

    UINavigationBar *barraNav = navVC.navigationBar;
    [barraNav setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    // HERE
    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    navItem = navVC.navigationItem;
    UIBarButtonItem *botonIzq = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bNavBarIzq.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
    [navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:botonIzq];

    self.window.rootViewController = navVC;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A navigation item is not a feature of a navigation controller but of one of its children. It is the `menuVC` whose navigation item should be set here.

Moreover, this should rightly be the job of `menuVC`, i.e. the code should be in its class - this is not the job of the app delegate (though there is nothing strictly wrong with that, it's just a "proper division of labor" type of thing).

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bNavBarIzq.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *botonIzq = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(YOUR_METHOD:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong navigation item.
You should use menuVC one, instead of navVC.

Just try:

```
UIBarButtonItem *botonIzq = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bNavBarIzq.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
menuVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = botonIzq;
```

Also, please, check this code:

```
// HERE
UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
navItem = navVC.navigationItem;
```

You've created navItem, and then override it. You should refactor it.